# Failed to upload huge size file to Office 365 site

Tags: file-upload, office-365

We have a Office 365 site. When we upload documents of few MB from Browser, they are successfully uploaded to document library but when we tried to upload file of size greater than 50MB, we get the connection closed/interrupted error

in IE, we get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PybFf.png

in Chrome, we get

https://i.stack.imgur.com/An5Nt.png

As far as I know, Office 365 support maximum of 250MB file size. Please let us know, if there is any settings/configuration we need to set either in client or server side.

Thanks in Advance.

Prakash

Comment: Maybe a corporate proxy between your computer and the web can interfere?

Answer (score 1):

Due to the multi-tenant nature of Office 365 SharePoint sites, the 250MB limit cannot be lifted for an individual tenant.